# Is it possible to shortcut a regular expression into matching?

Tags: java, regex, performance, optimization

I have a few regular expressions which are run against very long strings. However, the only part of the string which concerns the RE is near the beginning. Most of the REs are similar to:

```
\\s+?(\\w+?).*
```

The REs capture a few groups near the start, and don't care what the rest of the string is. For performance reasons, is there a way to have the RE engine avoid looking at all the characters consumed by the terminating `.*`?

Note: The application with the REs is written using the `java.regex` classes.

**Edit:** For example I have the following RE:

```
.*?id="number"[^>]*?>([^<]+?).*
```

Which is run against large HTML files which are stored as `StringBuilder`s. The tag with `id="number"` is always near the start of the HTML file.

Comment: Please post an example of some of the strings you are trying to match.

Comment: can we see the actual code you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the java.util.regex classes, there are a number of ways to match against a given string. `Matcher.matches` always matches against the *whole* input string. `Matcher.find` looks for something matching your regular expression *somewhere within* the input string. Finally, `Matcher.lookingAt` matches your regular expression against the *beginning* of your input string.

If you are using `Matcher.matches` you may require the `.*` at the end to match the whole string. However, you might be better off using one of the other methods instead, which would allow you to leave off the `.*`. It sounds like `Matcher.lookingAt` may be appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: I was using `Matcher.matches` when I wanted the behavior of `Matcher.find`, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just take out **.***, you dont need it.

```
^\\s+?(\\w+?)
```

Comment: That does not work for me. Removing the `.*` causing the matching to fail.

Comment: if \\s+?(\\w+?).* the whole regexp? or is it part of a bigger expression?

Comment: Ben, what are you trying to match and on what input does taking the .* out fail, using what specific java code?

Comment: i guess since you've chosen greg's answer that  you were using matches, which would explain why michael's answer didn't work for you.

Comment: Yup, once I switched over to `find()` removing the `.*` was possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?id="number"[^>]*?>([^<]+?).*
```

Is that really the regex you're using?  The reason I ask is because `([^<]+?)` will always match exactly one character, as if you had written `([^<])` instead. The `+` quantifier has to match at least once, but because it's reluctant it immediately hands off to the next part - `.*` - which always succeeds.  Removing the `.*` and switching to `find()` or `lookingAt()` won't change that behavior, either (although it will probably be a little quicker to get the same result).  If you want to match all the text up to the next angle bracket, you should get rid of the question mark: `([^<]+)` .

`[^>]*?>` doesn't make much sense, either.  You have to consume as many non-brackets as there are before you can match the bracket, so what's the point of making that quantifier reluctant?  In fact, there's no point making it greedy either; if `[^>]*` matches as much as it can and the next character isn't '>', you know backtracking won't do any good.  You might as well use a possessive quantifier - `[^>]*+>` - or an atomic group - `(?>[^>]*+)>` - if your regex flavor supports them.

The first quantified portion - `.*?` - is the only one that's used correctly (if not optimally).  Putting that at the beginning of a regex simulates the behavior of `find()` when you're using `lookingAt()` or (with a `.*` at the end) `matches()`.  However, leaving it off and using `find()` is more efficient, as you've discovered.

Reluctant quantifiers are very handy, but lately it seems like they've been getting overexposed.  With increasing frequency I see people giving the advice "Use reluctant quantifiers" with no explanation or qualification--just another silver bullet.  And I believe regexes like the one in this question are the result.  Of the three reluctant quantifiers, one should have been greedy, one should have been possessive, and the other shouldn't have been there at all.

EDIT: Here's an example to illustrate some of what I'm talking about, and to address Stephen C's comment.  Given this string:

```
<div id="number" class="whatever">abc123</div>
```

...the dynamic parts of the regex match like this:

```
.*?         => '<div '

[^>]*?      => ' class="whatever"'

([^<]+?)    => 'a'

.*          => 'bc123</div>'
```

Changing all the reluctant quantifiers to greedy doesn't change the overall match (the whole string), and it doesn't change what gets matched by the first two dynamic portions.  But the last two get reapportioned:

```
([^<]+)     => 'abc123'

.*          => '</div>'
```

Looking at the original regex, I thought this must be the desired result; why use such a complicated subexpression inside a capturing group if not to capture the whole content, `'abc123'`?  That's what leads me to believe the reluctant quantifiers were used blindly, as a panacea.

One other thing: looking back over the thread, I see the OP didn't actually *say* he had removed the `.*?` from the front of the regex when he switched to the `find()` method.  @Ben, if you haven't done that, you should; it's just slowing things down now.  That would leave you with this regex:

```
id="number"[^>]*+>([^<]+)
```

I don't want anyone to think I'm contesting the accepted answer, either.  I'm just scratching this itch I have about the overuse/inappropriate use of reluctant quantifiers.

Comment: Use of greedy versus reluctant quantifiers only affects the order in which the alternatives are tried.  If the pattern does not match, the regex engine has to try all alternatives anyway.

Comment: @Stephen: yes, but it can change which *parts* of the regex match which parts of the input.  I added an example to my answer; it's too complicated for a comment (even with all these nice new formatting options).

Comment: The reluctant modifier also forces the regex engine to consult the next possible match for every step forward, possibly resulting in extensive unneeded branching and backtracking as in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with HTML, regular expressions are not the right tool to do the analysis unless you have 100% control over the data files.  It will eventually break.

It looks to me that you need the content of the tag which has id="number" and apparently  more too.  Lenient parsers exist allowing XSLT transformation on HTML input, which might be exactly what you need.  I will look it up if you are interested.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you have control over your data files, there is NO right tool for parsing HTML.  The world is full of HTML files that break the various spec, and will trip up any of the regular Java HTML parsers.  For example, an XSLT transform will fail if the HTML is not readable as (well-formed) XML.

Comment: Using regular expressions was a design decision we made. The regular expressions allow us to be a little fuzzy in how we find the data. Whereas HTML-specific solutions typically expect the markup to have specific layout with exact IDs and a known element hierarchy.

Comment: @Stephen C, when I say "Lenient parsers exists allowing XSLT with HTML input" I mean that HTML parsers actually exists which either builds a DOM tree or a SAX stream.  I recall having read that the HTML parser in Swing can be tweaked to do this.  If I was referring to well-formed XHTML I would have said so :-)

Comment: @Ben S, XPath expressions allow you to easily select the text of the node which has an attribute named "id" with the value "number".

Comment: Such a Java answer.  His concern was the regex needing to parse the whole string.  Your answer to parse the whole string into a DOM so that you can then do the search.  I don't even want to start with the SAX alternative.  Don't get me wrong I totally agree with your sentiment, but its not globally applicable.  If you are going to break down the entirety of an HTML or XML document regex is not the way to do it.  With just the short snippet of what he is doing, regex is the right answer for the job.  It will much more quickly and reliably pull one piece of information out of a document.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great library for dealing with HTML files--including badly formed, real-world ones: BeautifulSoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

It would be very easy to find your id= tag with this library

Answer (score 0):

In this case particular case, the simple answer was to use 'find' rather than 'matches'.  But if that doesn't work for you, the Java Pattern class supports regexes with so-called possessive quantifiers that can be used to prevent backtracking.

Possessive quantifiers are the 3rd alternative to greedy and reluctant quantifiers.  The syntax is in Java is 'X?+' or 'X*+' or 'X++'.  Possessive quantifiers match as many characters as possible (like greedy quantifiers), but if the rest of the pattern does not match the possessive quantifier fails instead of backing off.  (Sort of like a "cut" in Prolog.)

But beware that using a possessive quantifier instead of a greedy or reluctant one will change the meaning of your pattern.

There is tutorial information about possessive quantifiers at [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).